# Pointer to integer conversion in C

Tags: c, pointers, c11

> C11 6.3.2.3/6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
> the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
> type.

The quote above, says that if value of a pointer expression after conversion to integer type is representable by integer its okey to convert it. But there is something bothers me. I looked to standard but i couldn't find how the pointer to int conversion takes place.

Let's say we have a pointer object, which pure binary interpretation of it equals to 0x100. If we convert it to an unsigned integer of enough precision, can we say that expression's value after conversion will be equal to 0x100 due to standard?

Or let me put it this way, is there a convention on how pointer objects represented on memory?

Comment: `the result is implementation-defined`

Comment: Single memory space, flat memory model systems have pointer to integer conversions that work the way you describe. But there were/are dual memory space (Harvard architecture), and segmented memory model (Intel 8086) systems where the conversion from pointer to integer is, shall we say, more interesting. So the C standard is deliberately saying nothing about how the conversion works. In fact, the point of the last sentence in that quote is that an implementation isn't required to support the conversion of pointers to integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the text you cite states, the result is *implementation-defined*. Per C 3.4.1, this is:

> unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made.

Thus, the C implementation you are using (primarily  the compiler)  is required to document how the result is determined.

In implementations with “flat” virtual address spaces, where each pattern of bits within a certain range represents an address, it is common to simply reinterpret the bits as a binary numeral. So the address 1 0000 0000 would be converted to the number 256.

However, implementations with some form of base-and-offset or segment-and-offset addressing might form an integer with the base in some bits and the offset in another, and there are other possibilities.